# Stanford NLP Tokens Regex -- doesn't recognize NER

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm just barely getting started with Tokens Regex. I haven't really found an intro or tutorial that gives me what I need. (If I've missed something, links are appreciated!)

The super short, bare-bones idea is that I want to do something like using

`pattern: ( ( [ { ner:PERSON } ]) /was/ /born/ /on/ ([ { ner:DATE } ]) )`

(from https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.html)

to match "John Smith was born on March 1, 1999", and then be able to extract "John Smith" as the person and "March 1, 1999" as the date.

I've cobbled together the following from a couple of web searches. I can get the simple Java regex `/John/` to match, but nothing I've tried (all copied from web searches for examples, and tweaked a bit) matches when I use an NER.

EDIT for clarity: (Success/failure at the moment is true/false from `matcher2.matches()` in the code below.)

I don't know if I need to explicitly mention some model or an annotation or something, or if I'm missing something else, or if I'm just approaching it entirely the wrong way.

Any insights are much appreciated! Thanks!

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.TokenSequenceMatcher;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.TokenSequencePattern;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.Annotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.junit.Test;

public class StanfordSandboxTest {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(StanfordSandboxTest.class);

    @Test
    public void testFirstAttempt() {

        Properties props2;
        StanfordCoreNLP pipeline2;
        TokenSequencePattern pattern2;
        Annotation document2;
        List<CoreMap> sentences2;
        TokenSequenceMatcher matcher2;
        String text2;

        props2 = new Properties();
        props2.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner, parse, dcoref");
        pipeline2 = new StanfordCoreNLP(props2);
        text2 = "March 1, 1999";
        pattern2 = TokenSequencePattern.compile("pattern: (([{ner:DATE}])");
        document2 = new Annotation(text2);
        pipeline2.annotate(document2);
        sentences2 = document2.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
        matcher2 = pattern2.getMatcher(sentences2);
        log.info("testFirstAttempt: Matches2: " + matcher2.matches());

        props2 = new Properties();
        props2.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, regexner, parse, dcoref");
        pipeline2 = new StanfordCoreNLP(props2);
        text2 = "John";
        pattern2 = TokenSequencePattern.compile("/John/");
        document2 = new Annotation(text2);
        pipeline2.annotate(document2);
        sentences2 = document2.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);
        matcher2 = pattern2.getMatcher(sentences2);
        log.info("testFirstAttempt: Matches2: " + matcher2.matches());
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting Q. Welcome to SO. You might find it helpful to provide examples of data that your code fails to match, and what you expect.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I should have been clearer I guess.

The data that I'm trying to match is in the code. `"March 1, 1999"` to match  `pattern: (([{ner:DATE}])` (`matcher2.matches()` gives false)
and  `"John"` to match `/John/` , for which `matcher2.matches()` gives true.

Comment: Got it... I wasn't looking hard enough at your example, which seems fine.

Comment: At this point, I'd just like a hardcoded `"John Smith"` to match a hardcoded `[{ner:PERSON}]` using `matches()` or `find()` for starters. Just to see I'm on the right track as far as putting the basic pieces together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample code:

```
package edu.stanford.nlp.examples;

import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;

import java.util.*;


public class TokensRegexExampleTwo {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // set up properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,tokensregex");
    props.setProperty("tokensregex.rules", "multi-step-per-org.rules");
    props.setProperty("tokensregex.caseInsensitive", "true");

    // set up pipeline
    StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

    // set up text to annotate
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation("Joe Smith works for Apple Inc.");

    // annotate text
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);

    // print out found entities
    for (CoreMap sentence : annotation.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
      for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get(CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class)) {
        System.out.println(token.word() + "\t" + token.ner());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sample rules file:

```
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }

$ORGANIZATION_TITLES = "/inc\.|corp\./"

$COMPANY_INDICATOR_WORDS = "/company|corporation/"

ENV.defaults["stage"] = 1

{ pattern: (/works/ /for/ ([{pos: NNP}]+ $ORGANIZATION_TITLES)), action: (Annotate($1, ner, "RULE_FOUND_ORG") ) }

ENV.defaults["stage"] = 2

{ pattern: (([{pos: NNP}]+) /works/ /for/ [{ner: "RULE_FOUND_ORG"}]), action: (Annotate($1, ner, "RULE_FOUND_PERS") ) }
```

This will apply NER tags to "Joe Smith" and "Apple Inc.".  You can adapt this to your specific case.  Please let me know if you want to do something more advanced than just apply NER tags.  Note: make sure you put those rules in a file called: "multi-step-per-org.rules".

Comment: Thanks very much for the response! I'll give it a try. I was under the impression that "ner" was already defined. Looking at your example, it appears we have to explicitly bind it to `CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation`? As for "more advanced than just apply NEW tags," I'm not sure yet. I'm still coming to grips with the terminology. Ultimately, I'll want to take "Joe Smith works for Apple Inc." and extract from that the facts that A) the person is Joe Smith and B) his employer is Apple Inc.

Comment: You should study edu.stanford.nlp.ie.KBPTokensRegexExtractor which is our code for processing relations, and the corresponding rules files in this jar: stanford-english-kbp-corenlp-2018-02-27-models.jar...specifically edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/english/tokensregex/per:employee_of.rules and edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/english/tokensregex/defs.rules

Comment: Hello @StanfordNLPHelp I have tried your solution in this answer, but I keep getting an error as I explain in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61235575/stanford-corenlp-server-error-while-reading-the-token-regex-rules-file-in-pyt . Do you have please any Idea why ? thks in advance.