# Stanford CoreNLP TokensRegex / Error while parsing the .rules file in Python

Tags: python, regex, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to solve this problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231337/annotate-author-names-using-regexner-from-the-stanfordnlp-library), but using regexner from the stanford nlp library was not possible.

(NB: I am using stanfordnlp library version 0.2.0, Stanford CoreNLP version 3.9.2, and Python 3.7.3)

So I wanted to try a solution using TokenRegex. 
As a first attempt I tried to use the token regex file tokenrgxrules.rules from this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143681/stanford-nlp-tokens-regex-doesnt-recognize-ner):

```
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }

$ORGANIZATION_TITLES = "/inc\.|corp\./"

$COMPANY_INDICATOR_WORDS = "/company|corporation/"

ENV.defaults["stage"] = 1

{ pattern: (/works/ /for/ ([{pos: NNP}]+ $ORGANIZATION_TITLES)), action: (Annotate($1, ner, "RULE_FOUND_ORG") ) }

ENV.defaults["stage"] = 2

{ pattern: (([{pos: NNP}]+) /works/ /for/ [{ner: "RULE_FOUND_ORG"}]), action: (Annotate($1, ner, "RULE_FOUND_PERS") ) }
```

And here is my python code:

```
import stanfordnlp


from stanfordnlp.server import CoreNLPClient
# example text
print('---')
print('input text')
print('')
text = "The analysis of shotgun sequencing data from metagenomic mixtures raises complex computational challenges. Part of the difficulty stems from the read length limitation of existing deep DNA sequencing technologies, an issue compounded by the extensive level of homology across viral and bacterial species. Another complication is the divergence of the microbial DNA sequences from the publicly available references. As a consequence, the assignment of a sequencing read to a database organism is often unclear. Lastly, the number of reads originating from a disease causing pathogen can be low (Barzon et al., 2013). The pathogen contribution to the mixture depends on the biological context, the timing of sample extraction and the type of pathogen considered. Therefore, highly sensitive computational approaches are required."
text = "In practice, its scope is broad and includes the analysis of a diverse set of samples such as gut microbiome (Qin et al., 2010), (Minot et al., 2011), environmental (Mizuno et al., 2013) or clinical (Willner et al., 2009), (Negredo et al., 2011), (McMullan et al., 2012) samples."
print(text)
# set up the client
print('---')
print('starting up Java Stanford CoreNLP Server...')
#I am not sure if I can add here the tokensregex rules
prop={'regexner.mapping': 'rgxrules.txt', "tokensregex.rules": "tokenrgxrules.rules", 'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,regexner,tokensregex'}


# set up the client


with CoreNLPClient(properties=prop,timeout=100000, memory='16G',be_quiet=False ) as client:
    # submit the request to the server
    ann = client.annotate(text)
    # get the first sentence
    sentence = ann.sentence[0]
```

Here is the result I get:

```
    Starting server with command: java -Xmx16G -cp /Users/stanford-corenlp-full-2018-10-05//* edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 100000 -threads 5 -maxCharLength 100000 -quiet False -serverProperties corenlp_server-f8a9bab3cb0b44da.props -preload tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,tokensregex
[main] INFO CoreNLP - --- StanfordCoreNLPServer#main() called ---
[main] INFO CoreNLP - setting default constituency parser
[main] INFO CoreNLP - warning: cannot find edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz
[main] INFO CoreNLP - using: edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz instead
[main] INFO CoreNLP - to use shift reduce parser download English models jar from:
[main] INFO CoreNLP - http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html
[main] INFO CoreNLP -     Threads: 5
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.tagger.maxent.MaxentTagger - Loading POS tagger from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/english-left3words/english-left3words-distsim.tagger ... done [0.6 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.8 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [1.1 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier - Loading classifier from edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.distsim.crf.ser.gz ... done [0.6 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.time.JollyDayHolidays - Initializing JollyDayHoliday for SUTime from classpath edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/jollyday/Holidays_sutime.xml as sutime.binder.1.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.time.TimeExpressionExtractorImpl - Using following SUTime rules: edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/defs.sutime.txt,edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.sutime.txt,edu/stanford/nlp/models/sutime/english.holidays.sutime.txt
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator - ner.fine.regexner: Read 580704 unique entries out of 581863 from edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/english/gazetteers/regexner_caseless.tab, 0 TokensRegex patterns.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator - ner.fine.regexner: Read 4869 unique entries out of 4869 from edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/english/gazetteers/regexner_cased.tab, 0 TokensRegex patterns.
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexNERAnnotator - ner.fine.regexner: Read 585573 unique entries from 2 files
```

Everything is working fine until it starts parsing the tokenregex.rules file:

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokensregex
[main] ERROR CoreNLP - Could not pre-load annotators in server; encountered exception:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing file: Users/Documents/utils/tokenrgxrules.rules
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(CoreMapExpressionExtractor.java:293)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(CoreMapExpressionExtractor.java:275)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexAnnotator.<init>(TokensRegexAnnotator.java:77)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.tokensregex(AnnotatorImplementations.java:78)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$6(StanfordCoreNLP.java:524)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$30(StanfordCoreNLP.java:602)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:126)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:149)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:251)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:192)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:188)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer.main(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:1505)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "Users/Documents/utils/tokenrgxrules.rules" as class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:480)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readerFromString(IOUtils.java:617)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(CoreMapExpressionExtractor.java:287)
    ... 12 more
[main] INFO CoreNLP - Starting server...
[main] INFO CoreNLP - StanfordCoreNLPServer listening at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO CoreNLP - [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:49907] API call w/annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,tokensregex
In practice, its scope is broad and includes the analysis of a diverse set of samples such as gut microbiome (Qin et al., 2010), (Minot et al., 2011), environmental (Mizuno et al., 2013) or clinical (Willner et al., 2009), (Negredo et al., 2011), (McMullan et al., 2012) samples.
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator lemma
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ner
[pool-1-thread-3] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokensregex
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing file: Users/Documents/utils/tokenrgxrules.rules
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(CoreMapExpressionExtractor.java:293)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(CoreMapExpressionExtractor.java:275)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TokensRegexAnnotator.<init>(TokensRegexAnnotator.java:77)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.tokensregex(AnnotatorImplementations.java:78)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$getNamedAnnotators$6(StanfordCoreNLP.java:524)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.lambda$null$30(StanfordCoreNLP.java:602)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy$3.compute(Lazy.java:126)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:31)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:149)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:251)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:192)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.<init>(StanfordCoreNLP.java:188)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer.mkStanfordCoreNLP(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:368)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer.access$800(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:50)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer$CoreNLPHandler.handle(StanfordCoreNLPServer.java:855)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:83)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:82)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:79)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:647)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "Users/Documents/utils/tokenrgxrules.rules" as class path, filename or URL
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:480)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readerFromString(IOUtils.java:617)
    at edu.stanford.nlp.ling.tokensregex.CoreMapExpressionExtractor.createExtractorFromFiles(CoreMapExpressionExtractor.java:287)
    ... 23 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/stanfordnlp/server/client.py", line 330, in _request
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "/Users/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http://localhost:9000/?properties=%7B%27outputFormat%27%3A+%27serialized%27%7D
```

I looked for hours for a solution to this problem but couldn't find any, I have also tried the code basic_NER from the official [stanford](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html) nlp page but it gives me the same error. I code in python so I couldn't test their Java code.

Any help or link can be super helpful.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be happening with stanza 1.0.0 and Stanford CoreNLP 3.9.2, and the team is working on it. I believe it means something else is trying to use the same port, and the server is silently failing.  You should verify first you can get the server running outside of the Python client.  Since you're seeing this error I think the server isn't even starting.

Comment: Hello thank you for very much for your answer, but I don't think it's due to the server failure because the code works correctly when I remove the 'tokensregex.rules' file from the properties (for example it works correctly for the regexner file). I have updated the answer to include the whole error log. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

We really have balkanized our help resources, haven't we?

Check out this line:

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "Users/Documents/utils/tokenrgxrules.rules" as class path, filename or URL`

I suspect it is trying to come up with a relative path and not succeeding.  What happens if you replace `tokenrgxrules.rules` with an absolute path to the file?